# PostgreSQL- Cannot connect to server

Tags: macos, terminal, postgresql

**PREFACE:** I just bought my first Mac laptop a week ago so that I could get some work done on my trip, but so far I've spent most of my time trying to solve an issue with PostgreSQL. Something went wrong and I don't know what caused it.

**SPECS:**

Macbook Air OS X Yosemite (10.10.5)

psql (PostgreSQL) 9.4.4 installed with Homebrew

**ISSUE:** I receive this error when attempting to connect to my database:

```
2015-09-28 16:18:18 ERROR  : ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/share/postgresql/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
2015-09-28 16:44:23 ERROR  : Error connecting to the server: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I've tried a bunch of different things to fix it, but Ive gotten nowhere. As far as I can tell, `/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432` does not exist on my system, but I may not have found the correct search syntax. I've been using `find ~ -name ".s.PGSQL.5432"`. How should I go about troubleshooting this?

**EDIT**: Following up on a comment:

Attempting to run `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start` results in the following experience:

```
$ pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start
pg_ctl: could not open PID file "/usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid": Permission denied
$ sudo pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start
pg_ctl: cannot be run as root
Please log in (using, e.g., "su") as the (unprivileged) user that will
own the server process.
$ su PostgreSQL
Password:
bash-3.2$ pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start
pg_ctl: could not open PID file "/usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid": Permission denied
bash-3.2$ sudo pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start

We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

Password:
postgres is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
bash-3.2$
```

It seems that it is asking me to run a sudo command from an unprivileged user account. I don't quite know what to do with that. Should this be placed in a seperate question?

Comment: I think the last paragraph is this question and you need to edit it to make it clearer - posters usually runs under user postgres so you will need an admin account or use [Postgres.app](http://postgresapp.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that you don't have an instance of PostgreSQL running right now.

Try to rerun your instance of PostgreSQL:

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start
```

Comment: `$ pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres` . 
`pg_ctl: no operation specified
Try "pg_ctl --help" for more information.`

Comment: @AdamStarrh sorry, please look at the updated answer

Comment: I've tried that, added it to the question

Comment: @AdamStarrh Press CTRL+D to log out from `postgres` user and try to run `sudo pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start` (you should be logged in as user with administrator privileges)

Comment: I get: `pg_ctl: cannot be run as root
Please log in (using, e.g., "su") as the (unprivileged) user that will
own the server process.` which is why I had switched to the PostgreSQL account..

Comment: @AdamStarrh ok, then just try to run it without sudo with the same user

Comment: `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start
pg_ctl: could not open PID file "/usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid": Permission denied` The file `postmaster.pid` is actually I file I had deleted in my troubleshooting steps, as this seemed to fix for alot of other people.

Comment: @AdamStarrh strange. try to run `sudo chown -R postgres /usr/local/var/postgres/` and then try to run pg_ctl from postgres user once again

Comment: Permission no longer denied! It still does not allow me to run the original command as root. When I run it via the PostgreSQL user: `pg_ctl: directory "/usr/local/var/postgres" is not a database cluster directory`
'`

Comment: @AdamStarrh that's strange because it's a usual location of postgrsql data folder for homebrew. What are contents of your `/usr/local/var/postgres` folder?

Comment: I ran `initdb -D /usr/local/var/postgres` and it seemed to spin it back up!! I can run it now with `postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres/` Now I just have to figure out how to get my user roles back, but this helped me tremendously!